# custom page in Drupal

Tags: drupal

hi i have created a website in drupal.In this registration page can be access by following url
http://mysite.com?q=user/register 
But i want to make a custom page  for registration.
Please give me some guide line , i don't have any idea for this

Answer (score 1):

You want to modify the user registration form,

http://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=user+registration+template+drupal&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=Jn0dTdTzI466sQP4uZ2PCg

Answer (score 1):

a) hook_form_user_register_alter() documentation at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6 b) if you totally cant do what you want with a happy little form altering then you can always hook_menu_alter() the page and use whatever page callback you desire instead of drupal_get_form.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto admin/build/modules
2. Enable Profile module
3. Add fields in profile and while adding a field make it 'visible during registration'